# Match a string and print lines from the same block matching another string

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a large file with more than 5000 lines in the following format

Below snippet shows two blocks of the file.

```
string name    : abcd

    used :metric
    test :ok

{


 fun: add

 fun: sub

 fun: mul

 fun: div

}   


string name    : degh

    used: non -metric
    test: good

{


 fun: per

 fun: div

 fun: add

 fun: mul


}
```

What I need is to search for the `string name` (eg: `abcd`) , and then print the values after `fun :` from that `string name`'s block

I would like the following output:

```
abcd    add
abcd    sub
abcd    mul
abcd    div
degh    per
degh    div
degh    add
degh    mul
```

What would be the proper way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

One of ways to approach it is with perl:

```
$ perl -lane '$hold=$F[3] if $_ =~ "^string name.*";print "$hold $F[1]" if $F[0] eq "fun:"' bigfile.txt                                                                
abcd add
abcd sub
abcd mul
abcd div
degh per
degh div
degh add
degh mul
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

RE_NAME='^ *string name *:' # regex for the 'name' line
RE_FUNSTART='^ *[{] *$'  # regex for the start of the 'fun' block
RE_FUNEND='^ *[}] *$'  # regex for end of 'fun' block
RE_FUN='^ *fun:'  # regex for 'fun' line

while read line; do
 if [[ $line =~ $RE_NAME ]]; then
     name="${line##*: }"
     echo
 elif [[ $line =~ $RE_FUNSTART ]]; then
     fun='1'
 elif [[ $line =~ $RE_FUNEND ]]; then
     fun=''
 elif [[ ($line =~ $RE_FUN) && (-n $fun) ]];  then   # match 'fun' lines only inside 'fun' block
     echo "$name    ${line##*: }"
 fi

done < your_big_file
```

Bash may be a bit slow for big files. If it is too slow for you, you could port the code to for example Perl or Python.

Comment: Hi Florian , First Thanks for quick support.   But i have several functions in single block. I want to send the file for your reference, how can i send you the file ?, as i am new here

Comment: You can use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and than post url.

Comment: i added one block of a big file, file is big 1000 lines with several blocks. http://pastebin.com/dtGuHwb5

Comment: Hi letizia/florin,  can u pl advice

Comment: we need to find a pattern or a rule, for examples: `Device Symmetrix Name : xxx` is always what you want to get and add to the subsequent `Front Director Paths` table?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with awk:

```
 awk '{ if ($1 == "string") name = $4; else if ($1 == "fun:") print name " " $2; }' your_file
```

Assuming that "`string name`" and "`:`" are separated by space and "`fun`" is always followed by "`:`" without space.